# I'm getting this Error while sending the form

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

AvailableSomething Went WrongSMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting.
My Password and email is correct, and my SSL is open.
This is my code:

```
<?php
echo !extension_loaded('openssl')?"Not Available":"Available";
$news = $_REQUEST['news'];
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$mail= new PHPMailer;
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port=587;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->SMTPSecure='ssl';
$mail->Username='omer.subohh@gmail.com';
$mail->Password='mypassword';
$mail->setFrom('omer.subohh@gmail.com', 'FixHub');
$mail->addAddress('omer.subohh@gmail.com', 'FixHub');     //Add a recipient
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'New Subscriber For FixHub NewsLetters';
$mail->Body = '<h2>'.$news.'</h2>';
if(!$mail->send())
{
  echo "Something Went Wrong";
  echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: As you would have learned when you followed the link to the troubleshooting guide in the error message, the combination of `ssl` encryption mode and port 587 will not work. You need port 465 to use that mode. You’re also running a very old and unsupported version that may be vulnerable to attacks, so upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

You should change ssl://smtp.gmail.com to smtp.gmail.com

And change SMTPSecure to "tls"

The hostname should not include the encryptiontype

Comment: still the same error

Comment: @Abdulrahman

I have edited my answer, check now

Comment: Still got the same error

Comment: Nope, the `ssl` prefix will do just fine.

Comment: @Synchro It will do fine, although google itself advises to use TLS.

Comment: [RFC8314](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8314) says otherwise.